# Hide dropdown box while entering value in the textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a Dropdown Box with JavaScript once someone is entering text inside a textarea.

This is what I did so far:

HTML

```
<table>
    NOTES OF A POST MORTEM EXAMINATION ON THE BODY OF A<br> 
    <select name="select86" id="travel_arriveVia" onchange='CheckColors86(this.value);'> 
        <option>Select</option> 
        <option value="Cattle">Cattle</option>
        <option value="Buffalo">Buffalo</option>
        <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
        <option value="Camel">Camel</option>
        <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="Sheep">Sheep</option>
        <option value="Pig">Pig</option>
        <option value="Goat">Goat</option>
        <option value="Deer">Deer</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>   
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>    
            <textarea rows="3" cols="25" name="div86" id="color86" style='display:none'></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
function CheckColors86(val)
{   
    var element=document.getElementById('color86');
        if(val=='Others')
        element.style.display='block';
    else  
        element.style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery you can do it like that:

```
$('#color86').keyup(function() {
    $('#travel_arriveVia').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Here the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ezd5ajmf/

Or as Snippet:

```js
$('#color86').keyup(function() {
   $('#travel_arriveVia').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  NOTES OF A POST MORTEM EXAMINATION ON THE BODY OF A<br> 
  <select name="select86" id="travel_arriveVia"> 
        <option>Select</option> 
        <option value="Cattle">Cattle</option>
        <option value="Buffalo">Buffalo</option>
        <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
        <option value="Camel">Camel</option>
        <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="Sheep">Sheep</option>
        <option value="Pig">Pig</option>
        <option value="Goat">Goat</option>
        <option value="Deer">Deer</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>   
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>    
        <textarea rows="3" cols="25" name="div86" id="color86"></textarea>
      </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function CheckColors86(val)
{

    var element=document.getElementById('color86');
        if(val=='Others')
        element.style.display='block';
    else  
        element.style.display='none';
}
function hideDropDown(){
  var element=document.getElementById('travel_arriveVia');
  element.style.display='none';
}
function showDropDown(){
  var element=document.getElementById('travel_arriveVia');
  element.style.display='block';
}
```

```html
<table>
        NOTES OF A POST MORTEM EXAMINATION ON THE BODY OF A<br> 
        <select name="select86" id="travel_arriveVia" onchange='CheckColors86(this.value);'> 
                        <option>Select</option> 
                        <option value="Cattle">Cattle</option>
                        <option value="Buffalo">Buffalo</option>
                        <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
                        <option value="Camel">Camel</option>
                        <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
                        <option value="Sheep">Sheep</option>
                        <option value="Pig">Pig</option>
                        <option value="Goat">Goat</option>
                        <option value="Deer">Deer</option>
                        <option value="Others">Others</option>
                    </select>   
                    <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <td>    
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="25" name="div86" id="color86" onfocus='hideDropDown()'></textarea>

                </td>
                </table>
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Its working but when click on the outside of textarea it displays the hidden dropdown box again .... how to solve it

Comment: just remove the function in onblur or checkout my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function in java script and call it on keyup event as below

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="25" name="div86" id="color86" style='display:none' onkeyup="toggleListOption();"></textarea>


function toggleListOption(){
    var el=document.getElementById('color86');
    if(el.value===""){
        document.getElementById('travel_arriveVia').style.display='block';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('travel_arriveVia').style.display='none';
    }
}
```